# MacBook can't see Cinema Display USB hub without restart; Is there a way to do a "discover USB devices" without restarting?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, catalina, cinema-display

I have a 15" MacBook Pro and a 24" Apple Cinema Display.

The Display has three connectors ... Mini Display Port + USB + Power ...   and I have an Apple USB keyboard and Logitech USB mouse plugged into the USB ports on the back of the Cinema Display.

I have used this setup for years with macOS Sierra (and earlier OS versions).  The MacBook always immediately saw the keyboard and mouse when I plug the Cinema Display's USB to the MacBook Pro.

I recently upgraded to the macOS Catalina (10.15.1) and ever since then, when I plug the Cinema Display USB into the MacBook Pro, the Mac doesn't see the keyboard and mouse until I restart the MacBook Pro.

Why does this happen?  And is there a way to tell the MacBook to do a "discover USB devices" or something without restarting the MacBook?